Overwrite specific image pixels with python
I have two images, both have the same dimensions (8192x4096), same number of channels (RGB). First have x numbers of colors and second have x + y numbers of colors.
I am getting colors of 1st image using Image.getcolors() (~10000 colors) from pillow. Now I want to go through the 2nd image and if pixel color does not exist in 1st image I want to put it into 1st image.
I tried to iterate through every pixel of 2nd image (both using Image.load() from PIL and converting it to numpy.array()) and check if color exist in 1st image and then overwrite it, but it is super slow. Any ideas how to do that faster?
My attempts:
provincesImage = Image.open(provinces)
provincesImagePixels = provincesImage.load()
voronoiImage = Image.open(voronoi)
voronoiImagePixels = voronoiImage.load()
voronoiImageColors = voronoiImage.getcolors(256*256*256)
for i in range(provincesImage.size[0]): # for every pixel:
    for j in range(provincesImage.size[1]):
        if provincesImagePixels[(i,j)] not in voronoiImageColors:
            voronoiImagePixels[(i,j)] = provincesImagePixels[(i,j)]


provincesImage = Image.open(provinces)
voronoiImage = Image.open(voronoi)
voronoiImageColors = voronoiImage.getcolors(256*256*256)
provincesImageArray = np.array(provincesImage)
voronoiImageArray = np.array(voronoiImage)
for i in range(provincesImageArray.shape[0]):
    for j in range(provincesImageArray.shape[1]):
        if tuple(provincesImageArray[i][j]) not in voronoiImageColors:
            voronoiImageArray[i][j] = provincesImageArray[i][j]



for loops are the wrong approach here - as is nearly always the case with image processing in Python. Convert your images to Numpy arrays and use np.unique() and np.setdiff1d().
